# Application-specific directories are erased when deploying

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I occasionally develop personal applications with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.5.4 and Xamarin.android.
When I deploy a project with this version, application-specific directories or files (in Android > data > appName > ...) are sometimes (in fact often) erased.

I wish to know if it's possible to avoid this happening and how.

Regards

Comment: Can you provide more information about the data which has been delated and what data you want to protect?

Comment: The only application-specific directories I use and are sometimes erased when deploying are documents directories ContextWrapper..GetExternalFilesDirs(null)[0 or 1].AbsolutePath ie /storage/0123-4567/Android/data/Myapp1/files and 
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/My.app1/files.

Comment: Files will be erased if the app is removed, but not if it is updated in place.

Comment: As far as I know it’s an on-site update. it didn’t happen with previous vs versions. Tanks.